# How can I change generated name for canvas image?

Tags: html, canvas

In FF when I do right-click on canvas and select "Save Image As ..." the offered name is canvas.png always. Could't I change it?

Comment: I too have started tinkering with this. Any luck? Thought maybe the `title` attribute might help, but it's a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're using to get that right-click functionality (unless its built into a particular browser), but either way the answer is "no" unless you are going to generate a new file on your server to put as a glass-pane over the canvas for right-click purposes.

Or a little more simply, you can't define in JavaScript the name of any particular file, it has to be decided on the server or not at all.

Comment: Sorry, I must clarify this: in FF when I right-click on a canvas and select "Save Image As...".

Comment: Using the `canvas` HTML5 tag, you can right click and choose 'Save Image As...'. Since the element is rendered in the browser via JS, no real file is being delivered by the server. I was hoping there would be a way to suggest a title or filename for the save file dialog.